# Wrapping the observer pattern with Cython

Tags: c++, python, design-patterns, cython

The observer pattern appears frequently in my C++ project, which I now want to expose to the Python interpreter via Cython bindings. I tried to construct a minimal example illustrating the situation. A `Spectacle` accepts any object derived from the abstract base class `Observer`,  such as an `Onlooker`.  When we call `Spectacle::event()`, each registered observer is notified.

This is the content of the file `ObserverPattern.h`:

```
class Spectacle {
private:
    std::vector<Observer*> observers;
public:

    Spectacle() {};
    virtual ~Spectacle() {};

    virtual void registerObserver(Observer* observer) {
        this->observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    virtual void event() {
        std::cout << "event triggered" << std::endl;
        for (Observer* observer : this->observers) {
            observer->onEvent();
        }
    }
};

class Observer {
public:
    Observer() {};
    virtual ~Observer() {};
    virtual void onEvent() = 0;

};

class Onlooker : public Observer {
public:
    Onlooker() {};
    virtual ~Onlooker() {};
    virtual void onEvent() {
        std::cout << "event observed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And this is the content of my `.pyx` file, containing the bindings:

```
    cdef extern from "ObserverPattern.h":
        cdef cppclass _Spectacle "Spectacle":
            _Spectacle() except +
            void registerObserver(_Observer* observer)
            void event()

    cdef extern from "ObserverPattern.h":
        cdef cppclass _Observer "Observer":
            _Observer() except +
            void onEvent()

    cdef extern from "ObserverPattern.h":
        cdef cppclass _Onlooker "Onlooker":
            _Onlooker() except +
            void onEvent()

    cdef class Spectacle:
        cdef _Spectacle _this

        def event(self):
            self._this.event()

        def registerObserver(self, Observer observer):
            self._this.registerObserver(observer._this)

   cdef class Observer:
        cdef _Observer* _this   # must be a pointer because _Observer has pure virtual method

    cdef class Onlooker(Observer):
        pass   # what should be the class body?
```

This does compile, but segfaults when `event()` is called and the observers are notified:

```
>>> spec = CythonMinimal.Spectacle()
>>> look = CythonMinimal.Onlooker()
>>> spec.registerObserver(look)
>>> spec.event()
event triggered
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What is the problem here and how could a fix look like?

Comment: Create cdef class Observer in a similar way you've done with Spectacle and then `def registerObserver(self, Observer observer): self._this.registerObserver(&observer._this)`.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak I've expanded the example and incorporated your advice, but there is still a problem. Note that `observer._this` cannot be an instance of `_Observer` because `_Observer` is abstract (has a pure virtual method). I've changed it to `_Observer*` to make it compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is essentially "implement a C++ interface in Python".

The only portable way to do this is to write an actual C++ class
that will call back into Python.

Cython has undocumented [`experimental_cpp_class_def`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/cpp_classes_def.pyx) option that allows to
create C++ classes using Cython syntax. It's not pretty (IMO), but it works 
for many scenarios.

Here is how you could implement `Observer` that delegates to the provided
Python callable:

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject, Py_INCREF, Py_DECREF

cdef cppclass ObserverImpl(_Observer):
    PyObject* callback

    __init__(object callback):  # constructor. "this" argument is implicit.
        Py_INCREF(callback)
        this.callback = <PyObject*>callback

    __dealloc__():  # destructor
        Py_DECREF(<object>this.callback)

    void onEvent():
        (<object>this.callback)()  # exceptions will be ignored
```

And that's how you could use it:

```
def registerObserver(self, callback not None):  # user passes any Python callable
    self._this.registerObserver(new ObserverImpl(callback))
```

C++ objects, just like C structures, can't hold Cython-managed `object`
references. That's why you have to use `PyObject*` field and manage reference
counting yourself. Inside methods you can, of course, cast to  and use any Cython feature.

Another tricky moment is exception propagation. `onEvent()` method, being defined in C++, can't propagate Python exceptions. Cython will simply ignore exceptions it can't propagate. If you want to do better, catch them yourself and store somewhere for later inspection or rethrow as C++ exception. (I think it's impossible to throw C++ exceptions in Cython syntax, but you can call an external throwing helper function.)

If your observer has more than one method, then `callback` would be a Python class and instead of calling it directly you would call its methods, like `(<object>this.callback).onEvent()`.

Obviously, `ObserverImpl` can also be coded directly in C++. `Py_INCREF`, `Py_DECREF` and `PyObject_Call`/`PyObject_CallMethod` are the only Python APIs necessary.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. As I feared, this is not at all trivial, but I'll try this out.

Comment: @Nikita Nemkin: is `void onEvent() except *:` the right syntax to propagate the exceptions? Or how do I do that?

Comment: `except` clauses only tell _Cython_ how to signal and check for exceptions. `onEvent` is called from _C++_ and C++ knows nothing about Python exception system. There is no simple solution for propagating Python exceptions across 3rd party stack frames. I've outlined the workarounds already: 1) ignore callback exceptions 2) store them and check later 3) piggyback on 3rd party error reporting system (like C++ exceptions).

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I only need to add 'with gil' to make the callbacks allow python object modification.